# Time-saving string manipulation for lists PHP-

Tags: php

I need to format users input for price lists, and would like to achieve this without using multiple form fields. If the user creates a list, for example:

```
  Eye Treatments<br />
  Eyebrow Tint $10<br />
  Eyelash Tint $15<br />
  Eyelash Extensions (brunched) Full Set $50
  <br /><br />
```

How can I format it like this?

```
<b>Eye Treatments</b>
 <ul>
 <li>Eyebrow Tint <span>$10</span></li>
 <li>Eyelash Tint <span>$15</span></li>
 <li>Eyelash Extensions<i>(brunched)</i> Full Set <span>$50</span></li>
 </ul>
```

Thanks for reading. Any help is appreciated. Lea

Comment: Are the `<br />` in the first example really `\n` ?

Comment: :) - Yes, when I put them into the database they get replaced with `\n`.

Comment: Are you not storing the user input *as is*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Input

```
Eye Treatments<br />
  Eyebrow Tint $10<br />
  Eyelash Tint $15<br />
  Eyelash Extensions (brunched) Full Set $50
  <br /><br />
```

#### PHP

```
$lines = explode('<br />', $str);
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines);

$newStr = '<b>' .  array_shift($lines) . '</b>' . "\n<ul>";

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (empty($line)) {
        continue;
    }

    preg_match_all('/^(?P<product>.*?) (?P<price>\$\d+)$/', $line, $matches);
    $newStr .= '<li>' . preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/', '<i>$0</i>', $matches['product'][0]) . ' <span>'  . $matches['price'][0] . '</span></li>' . "\n";
}

$newStr .= '</ul>';
echo $newStr;
```

[See it](http://ideone.com/BYWPp).

#### Output

```
<b>Eye Treatments</b> 
<ul><li>Eyebrow Tint <span>$10</span></li> 
<li>Eyelash Tint <span>$15</span></li> 
<li>Eyelash Extensions <i>(brunched)</i> Full Set <span>$50</span></li> 
</ul>
```

#### Assumptions

- That the `br` actually are `br` elements, most likely they are `\n` (replace `'<br />'` with `"\n"` if they are).
- Your string always looks like your example, and it is not embedded in other HTML.
- Your prices don't contain a decimal - it is trivial to add it, however.

#### Recommendations

- This method is flaky because it is very susceptible to being broken by an invalid pattern.
- Should that first `b` element really be a `h3` or something?

Comment: Yes, all input is consistant, and prices do not contain decimals, so your assumptions are safe. I check for incorrect formatting before submiting to db to avoid invalid entries. And the `<b>` will be a `<h4>`. Thanks:)

Comment: @Lea No worries, glad I could help you again :)